# Installation error LuaHPDF while installing

Tags: makefile, lua, pdf-generation

I want to install LuaHPDF. But it gives an error as follows. The LuaHPDF link is https://github.com/jung-kurt/luahpdf.

When I apply in terminal

```
$make
```

The error is

```
cc -shared -fPIC -o hpdf.so hpdf.o -lhpdf -lz -lpng -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:45: hpdf.so] Error 1
```

Can anyone help me?

I install libharu as requested.
https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/Installation#documentation-for-version-v230

Then I tried to install luaHPDF.

Comment: You need to install the `libz` (part of zlib) and `libpng` (part of PNG) libraries on your system.

Comment: Thanks you so much. It was successful. Anyone who's looking for the answer can go to this link. https://askubuntu.com/questions/508934/how-to-install-libpng-and-zlib